# Consumir una api con fetch de un json anidado

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch

Hola tengo el siguiente problema Quiero consumir una api la cual los datos los tiene anidados en el json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es lo que esta dentro de quotations
Este es mi código [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese mismo código me funciona de maravilla con apis como esta  https://api.datos.gob.mx/v1/gobmx.facts
cambiando el CONTAINER por results, como tal no se como hacer que obtenga los datos cuando el json esta anidado Container.quotations intente marcando error

Comment: has intentado `CONTAINER.quotations`?

Comment: si haces un log de `CONTAINER`, te regresa el objeto?

Comment: @hawks ya lo puse y marca error

Comment: que error te aparece, podrias compartirlo?

Comment: unexpected token, expected "," 113:31 que es al Poner CONTAINER.quotations

Comment: @Isaac como tal el problema radica creo en que la data en el Api si te das cuenta esta anidada no en CONTAINER y poner CONTAINER.quotation no funciono, no se como se deba recorrer cuando se anida

Comment: Te recomiendo que consultes la documentación de la api en cuestión en relación al acceso de los datos de la respuesta. SIno destructuras el JSON, que `typeof` y log tiene la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

```
({ CONTAINER: { quotations }, //etc )
```

Con eso se indica que también se hará destructuring de container y `quotations` es lo que se retorna